# Finding the SUM of data within (BETWEEN) selected variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

Checked everywhere but i couldn't find answer.

I've got this page where i use INNER JOIN to join two tables together, get their values and display them. I have this form that i use to get variables (eg. beginning date and ending date and card number) that will serve as the criteria for calling the values from the tables. I'm able to get the values posted by a particular card number (eg. A300) between a beginning date (eg. 1/1/13) and an ending date (eg. 15/1/13). My problem now is that i want to add values from a column (let's say it's called ORDER) between the beginning date and ending date.

Here's what i have so far:

```
$sql="SELECT transaction.date, transaction.card_number, orders.order, orders.details FROM transaction INNER JOIN orders USING (transaction_id) WHERE date BETWEEN '$begindate' AND '$enddate' AND card_number='$cardnumber'"; 
$result=mysqli_query($database,$sql);

$sum="SELECT SUM(order) WHERE date BETWEEN '$begindate' AND '$enddate' AND card_number = '$cardnumber'";
$sumresult=mysqli_query($database,$sum) or die(mysql_error());
$sumrow=mysqli_fetch_array($sumresult);
```

when i try to echo out the sum, it doesn't work. any help?

This is what i'd like to get:

```
   date     |     card number    |    order

 25/12/12   |       A025         |     550

 1/1/13     |       A300         |     400

 3/1/13     |       A300         |     600

 20/1/13    |       A300         |     250
```

in this case if my beginning date is 1/1/13 and my ending date is 15/1/13 and the card number is A300, the total order is supposed to be 1000

Thanks in advance!

EDIT::

here is the sql fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed080/9/0

Comment: Please, provide SQLfiddle for the 2-nd query, so we could see, what's wrong

Comment: Assuming that there are many `transaction dates` for every `card number`, would you like to show it all?

Comment: @491243 i only what to show the transactions made by a particular card number between the beginning and the ending dates

Comment: @admiralchip yep i get it, let's say you want to get records from `September 8, 2013 - September 9, 2013` and happens that a `cardNumber` has different transaction every day, in the result set, would you like to calculate the sum of `transaction` for each day or calculate all within the week?

Comment: @491243 i want to calculate the sum of transaction from a particular day (let's say sept. 8, 2013) to another date (let's say sept. 12, 2013). for example, if a cardNumber has transactions from sept. 1 right up to september 20, i want to know the sum from sept 8,9,10,11,12. i hope it makes sense.

Comment: Please note that you shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` [with date/time/timestamp type](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), or indeed any ranges involving varying-precision types.  Instead please explicitly your ranges with an inclusive lower-bound (`>=`) and an exclusive upper-bound (`<`).  Also, you're using mysqli, but still injecting values directly in the statement (essentially, still concatenating the string), which means you're still open to SQL Injection.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed080/9/0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DATE(transaction.date) date, 
        transaction.card_number, 
        SUM(orders.order) totalSum
FROM    transaction 
        INNER JOIN orders 
            USING (transaction_id) 
WHERE   date BETWEEN '$begindate' AND '$enddate' AND 
        card_number='$cardnumber'
GROUP   BY DATE(transaction.date), transaction.card_number
```

The query above will display the total amount of order in each day since it groups the record by `date` and `card_number`. But if you want to calcualate the total order within the specified range, you need to remove the `date` in the `GROUP BY` clause,

```
SELECT  transaction.card_number, 
        SUM(orders.order) totalSum
FROM    transaction 
        INNER JOIN orders 
            USING (transaction_id) 
WHERE   date BETWEEN '$begindate' AND '$enddate' AND 
        card_number='$cardnumber'
GROUP   BY transaction.card_number
```

Comment: my page comes out blank when i try it.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed080/9/0

there it is. it doesn't even the the entry from the 2/1/13 and there is no sum

Comment: is your date really saved in this format `1/1/13` => `d\m\yy`?

Comment: why are you not saving it in `DATE or DATETIME` data type?

Comment: what do you mean? (i'm pretty new in this!)

Comment: any help? i'm still waiting for a response.